# Bigger picture for facebook news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and looked into the news feed of a person with `/[userid]/feed`.

In this case, the person added a new cover photo which is at least 720px wide.
But in the news feed, all I found was a `picture` attribute containing a very small 130px wide thumbnail only.

Is there a way to access the full - or at least a bigger - picture within the API?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would anyone even use such a small picture to announce news?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the data coming back from the `/[userid]/feed` API call, you'll notice `"object_id": "xxx"` in the response.

If you make a second API call to this, e.g. `/xxx/`, you will get an array of images back with different sizes you can use. E.g.:

```
{
  "id": "000", 
  "created_time": "...", 
  "from": {
    ...
  }, 
  "height": 223, 
  "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif", 
  "images": [
    {
      "height": 480, 
      "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t31.0-8/1912152_448929725237759_238021965_o.jpg", 
      "width": 1547
    }, 
    {
      "height": 320, 
      "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t31.0-8/p320x320/1912152_448929725237759_238021965_o.jpg", 
      "width": 1031
    }, 
    {
      "height": 130, 
      "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t1.0-9/p130x130/1013838_448929725237759_238021965_n.jpg", 
      "width": 420
    }, 
    {
      "height": 225, 
      "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t31.0-8/p75x225/1912152_448929725237759_238021965_o.jpg", 
      "width": 725
    }
  ], 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/147587828705285/photos/a.448909598573105.1073741827.147587828705285/448929725237759/?type=1", 
  "picture": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t1.0-9/s130x130/1013838_448929725237759_238021965_n.jpg", 
  "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t31.0-8/q71/s720x720/1912152_448929725237759_238021965_o.jpg", 
  "updated_time": "2014-03-12T19:58:08+0000", 
  "width": 720
}
```